# GWT cell table auto refresh

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT cell table on one of the screen which is populated with the data coming from the service.
The requirement is that I have to provide auto-refresh functionality to that cell table so that user can view latest data every 5 minutes.
I am using GWT with Activities and Places in the project
I searched a lot but couldn't find any working solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of functionality if there is no any API provided fro gwt then you should go for a customized implementation.
In this you need to write a timer which has expire value of 5 mins.As timer expire you need to call your service to fetch the data and render it in to the GWT cell table.

[Here](http://coffeewithcode.com/2011/11/client-side-session-time-out-in-gwt/) is the link in which use of timer is shown.It is not the exactly one but it can help  to you create your own timer for 5mins. Hope this will help you.